# How to handle datetime on x-axis d3->implementation c3.js

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js, c3.js

i'm currently fighting with the presentation of some data which includes a value to a date.

The **data comes from php** - for testing i have written this values into a javascript var/array.

```
var allmydata = [
                      ['x1', "2018-01-15 00:08:00", "2018-01-15 01:08:00", "2018-01-15 02:08:00", "2018-01-15 03:08:00", "2018-01-15 04:08:00", "2018-01-15 05:08:00"],
                      ['x2', "2018-01-15 00:08:00", "2018-01-15 01:08:00", "2018-01-15 02:08:00", "2018-01-15 03:08:00", "2018-01-15 04:08:00", "2018-01-15 05:08:00"],
                      ['xn', "2018-01-15 00:08:00", "2018-01-15 01:08:00", "2018-01-15 02:08:00", "2018-01-15 03:08:00", "2018-01-15 04:08:00", "2018-01-15 05:08:00"],
                      ['data1', 10, 40, 20, 30, 140, 110],
                      ['data2', 20, 10, 50, 10, 240],
                      ['datan', 10, 10, 40, 280, 260]
          ];
```

for drawing the graph with c3.js is used this piece of code which works as long as i'm not using datetime x value.

i.e. this works (found on stackoverflow by mgraham):

```
var allmydata = [
                ['x1', 10, 30, 45, 50, 70, 100],
                ['x2', 30, 50, 75, 100, 120],
                ['xn', 45, 60, 80, 120, 130],
                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                ['data2', 20, 180, 240, 100, 190],
                ['datan', 10, 150, 220, 160, 300]
    ];

var match = function (dataStr) {
    return dataStr.startsWith("data") ? dataStr.replace ("data", "x") : undefined;
};

var xs = {};
allmydata.forEach (function (series) {
    var seriesName = series[0];
    var xsName = match (seriesName);
    if (xsName) {
        xs[seriesName] = xsName;
    }
});

var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            xs: xs,
            columns: allmydata
        }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0f38ffsy/1/

I would like to achieve the same thing but I need the date on the x-axis.

Comment: take a look at this example, it looks like its exactly what you want:- http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html

Comment: ok for working with seconds i have to parse the string for javascript format. new Date("2013-01-01 01:30:00").getTime()

Comment: got it need to use to concert php datetime to unix timestamp, also need to tell the diagram that i'm using time on x-axis. That was it. Now works fine.